# Page size when viewed at 100% is too large

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

Some of my customers are complaining that the website I put together using bootstrap is too big overall when viewed at 100% in Chrome. From everything to the size of the nav bar, to heros/containers/etc..it's too large at 100%.

How can I reduce the overall size of everything?

Comment: I would recommend just reducing the size of your artifacts, did you plan correctly for the customers' display widths and for other use cases? Ask for more specific feedback if you can..

Comment: @icedwater: Thanks for the reply. Not a lot of planning but overall there wasn't a lot of requirements for UIX size/etc,.  Reducing the size of each artifact including text seems logical. However, I was curious if there was a silverbullet style/asset that I could set and everything would scale down by a certain em or %.

Comment: Would be nice to have such a thing, but it might have some unexpected effects as well, since it would increase whitespace between the rest of the elements... the browser window stays at the same size, after all :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a [fixed width layout](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts) nothing should change size when resizing the browser.